# How to catch Natural Gas from Natural Gas Geysers to produce electricity?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I have found a [Natural Gas Geyser](http://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Natural_Gas_Geyser). I know that I can produce electricity with his emitted Gas with a [Natural Gas Generator](http://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Natural_Gas_Generator).

But how exactly do I do that?

Whatever I try, the most time, the Geyser seems to be inactive and the [Gas Pump](http://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Gas_Pump) and also the Natural Gas Generator doesn't work and doesn't produce electricity.

Are there different Geysers with different amounts of eruptions?

Comment: Check following things: Is there an excessive air pressure near the geysir, or generator? Is there anything in the piping between pump and generator? If so, is there any other gas present? That will likely block the gen. from working. You need to separate nat. gas from anything else by a filter setup.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @antipattern. I assume, the main reason is something called "over pressure". Do you know how I can handle it?

Comment: Not sure if that is the reason. It very well might be, but I had the impression that generators can build immense pressures (in other words, they dont care about air pressure). Sucking in gas into a pump from high pressure is not the issue, but the outlets will only release gas into a sane ambient pressure. What I rather suspect is that some other type of gas is blocking the generator. If you select the gen. I think there is an option to vent it.

Comment: are you trying to run the gas pump on the same curcuit that you're trying to power with the natural gas generator? as the gas won't pump without power, thus no gas will get to the generator

Comment: @ForceGaia I have a "hamster wheel" just for this purpose. But good idea!

Comment: @PeterCo yep, it's always good to rule out the silly mistakes first - I'm a programmer i do things like that all the time

Comment: Chances are you haven't hooked up the output pipe, but I'll cover everything in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may need to hook a power source up to the pump to get the Natural gas flowing.
2. It's always nice to have backup batteries to help avoid the no energy so no gas flow crisis.
3. Check the wiring and piping, you may have a vent at max pressure. I generally use a medium to large sized room outside of my base with an air scrubber or two posted up at the lowest point with the vent close by to ensure the gas in the immediate vicinity is caught and released while the large room ensures I'll have some time to react if the carbon starts to build up.
4. Maybe, just maybe, the geyser doesn't like you.

Comment: I assume, it is point 4 .-) but I will check 1-3 too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All geysers of the same type will output at the same average rate. For natural gas geysers, this averages 100g/s- almost enough for two generators.

When entering the cavern with the geyser, make sure you install an airlock to keep it separated from the rest of your base. Entering from the top is preferable as natural gas sinks below oxygen. Build your pump near the bottom and pipe it out of the cavern. A filter is optional but recommended- piping anything besides natural gas into the generators will damage them.

Build two generators nearby. Make sure there is space around them to handle the necessary infrastructure. Pipe the natural gas into them.

The natural gas generator has two outputs- CO<sub>2</sub> and polluted water, which you will need to deal with.

Polluted water will drain out of the machine onto the floor; it doesn't use a pipe. The best way to deal with it is to put the generators on a mesh floor and let it drain there. It's up to you whether you pump it out and use it or drain it into the rest of your base's polluted water. Getting rid of it isn't urgent as the generator doesn't produce very much water- it'll take 20 cycles to fill a single tile.

More importantly, you need to get rid of the CO<sub>2</sub>. The generator produces a lot of it and must output it via a pipe. **If this pipe is missing or blocked, the generator will not run**. The simplest way to get rid of the CO<sub>2</sub> is to pipe it to a Carbon Skimmer and place an output vent there.

If you do things right, this setup should get you a surplus of about 1000W, with room for expansion by adding fertilizer makers to make more gas.